# Jetty(?) breaks large js file on windows

Tags: java, javascript, windows, jetty

We use Jetty to deliver some js, css and html files, together with a jersey-powered REST API. I have a user running windows 7 32bit, German locale, that is encountering a very strange problem.

One of the js files is very large, about 14 000 LOC. When that file lands in the browser, somewhere along the way, it's been mangled. Specifically, 3981 lines of code has been moved from the middle of the file (at character no 370841, which is at line 9158), to the top of the file. This of course renders the file completely useless.

I have been unable to replicate this in other windows 7 32bit German installs, and I am running out of ideas as to what could be the cause of this.

I'm imagining that perhaps this is some limitation in file sizes that I am somehow hitting, but I'm not knowledgeable enough in Windows configurations to say where I should dig for more info.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you test with diferent browsers, even with wget or netcat ?

Comment: I've used jetty to serve big js files, which were generated on the fly without any problem. Check the other frameworks you're using as they're probably causing the problem. Specially, check any web app filter that you added to your web.xml and anything that wraps the request / OuputStream. Also, try opening the js file with an hex editor and check that there isn't an odd character on that position.

Comment: Maybe the server is reading UTF-8 and the JS is Windows-1252, but that should throw an Exception. Try native2ascii to make it UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your responses :) I've tried this in three different browsers. The stack we are using is JVM - Jetty - Jersey. We've been running it in production for 2 years on OSX, *nix and windows, never had problems. This problem only occurs on this one (two as of yesterday) German Windows 7 installs. There is no odd character at the given position, in fact, the position of the break differs between the two failing windows boxes. All text is UTF-8, throughout the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a firewall (ZoneAlarm) on the failing windows machines. I guess there is a limit to the size of HTTP packets it can handle or something.. Disabling ZoneAlarm solved the problem.

I'm gonna file a bug report with them.